# how to call a function in the controller after all directives in the ui are rendered

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

**background**

the angularjs page that i am building needs to show a ajax loader when the page is being rendered. the page has got a lot of directives and recursive calls. So it takes sometimes around 20 seconds for the page to finish rendering.

**Issue**

I am unable to find if all the directives in the page are finished rendering in the page.  How can i know if all the directives within the angularjs page has finished rendering in the ui.

**Question?**

I tried the following approach to find if all directives in the ui have finished rendering ....but it doesnt work as intended.

I have created a directive called initialisation and that is placed at the bottom of the page. And this directive sends a trigger when it is loaded.

```
var initialisation = function ($rootScope) {

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function($scope) {
                    var to;
                    var listener = $scope.$watch(function() {
                        clearTimeout(to);
                        to = setTimeout(function () {
                            console.log('initialised');
                            listener();
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('initialised');
                        }, 50);
                    });
                }
            };

}

app.directive('initialisation', initialisation);
```

In my page I have placed the directive

```
<form name="mainForm">
    <div data-ng-init="pageAnimateScrollToTop();" >
    <collection collection='md.fields' data='data' fulldata='data' initialisation></collection>   
   </div> 
 </form>
```

And in my controller I have a listener that will make a call to the javascript function

```
 $scope.$on("initialised", function () {
    //calls a javascript function
      doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Most often thank not, directives itself do not take that much time to render, are there number of remote calls involved?

Comment: That's a really really long time for an angular page to load! Sounds like you have some back end problems or are requesting too much data. Might want to do some profiling to see where your bottlenecks are

Comment: any clue what should i do to findout if the all the directives in the page have finished loading

Comment: Not really...short of setting up a service to track all the inital ajax calls ...rendering usually doesn't take long...unless you are creating far too many elements like many thousands of table rows or something. Again...do some profiling to see what takes so long. in today's world more than a few seconds is a long time

Comment: Also can use `$last` in an `ng-repeat` to know when a big repeater is done